# child_process cant input after some time

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am working on a live terminal in the browser over socket.io. And I encountered a problem.

My code:

```
child = require('child_process').spawn('cli opening command'),

//simple output to the client
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    io.emit('consoleOut', data);
});

//socket
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('consoleInput', (msg) => {
        //writing the message to the stdin stream
        child.stdin.write(msg + '\n');
    })
});
```

The Problem:

With this setup, the output is always "No such command '[user input]'..." only on the first input after the CLI was started it is working fine. And when I look at the output, I see that the first letter between the two quotes is an ASCII decimal 4 that equals to an end of transmission character.

Example (if I look at the string in the browser):

> No such command '\u0004set verbose 5'

And the weird thing is when I write to the stream and hardcode it, the commands are perfectly fine and get executed like they should. But if then a user inputs his command, again every command is not working, even the first one.

```
child.stdin.write('set verbose 5\n');
child.stdin.write('set verbose 3\n');
```

I can verify that it is not the user input because when I change the socket on the consoleInput function into:

```
child.stdin.write('test' + msg + '\n');
```

I still get the same output (if for example the user inputs set verbose 5):

> No such command '\u0004testset verbose 5'

(of course the command wouldn't work in the first place, but it's to show for the EOT chat)

My guess:

I get the EOT char only when I write to the buffer, and my string includes at least one \n.
Then everything until the last \n gets sliced out of the buffer, and there is then a EOT char left behind.
And It makes sense if this is true that I can input one command at the start that is working fine because there the whole buffer is empty and no EOT char is there.

Thanks, Julian ;)

Comment: try making `msg` into ascii and not unicode

Comment: Did you try to `console.log` your `command` and see what's coming back from the other end?

Comment: Can you cut down to the problem statement specifics in the question here and remove text/commentary that is not related to the one specific challenge you have such as "I would hope it's my code, but I don't find any mistakes. I hope you can help me, because I can't figure it out." This does not help clarify the problem statement here.

Comment: I redid the question, hope now it is ok. @MarkSchultheiss